# display warning when users enter a value greater than the actual value

Tags: vb.net

can anyone give me some idea how to write a code to display warning when users enter a value greater than the actual value, but it still can enter values ​​for other fields. I use VB.net and access database. I think it is able to use onchange but i still don't have any idea to write the code

here is example 
[image]

Comment: Your asp-classic tag is suspicious. Is it ASP.Net or some WinForm app talking to service implemented with asp-classic?

Comment: Is this VB.Net Winform or Asp.Net

Comment: i use vb 2008 and access database

Comment: Use the `ErrorProvider` component in the Toolbox.

Answer (score 0):

Use the built-in validation scheme. Example here :
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.data.binding.validatesondataerrors.aspx